# Evitar org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException cuando los argumentos empiezan con guión (-) en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Estoy programando un traductor de código morse en Kotlin, para la entrada utilizo los argumentos del método main:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
```

Utilizo org.apache.commons.cli para gestionar las opciones del comando (-d para decodificar y -e para codificar). La cosa es que al introducir código morse el programa lo confunde con opciones del comando (porque utiliza guiones).

Ejemplo de utilización del programa:

```
morse-translator -d --. .- .
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.cli.UnrecognizedOptionException: Unrecognized option: --.
```

Adjunto la clase que maneja las opciones del comando:

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine
import org.apache.commons.cli.DefaultParser
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options

class Input(args: Array<String>) {
private var flags: Options = Options()
private var parser: DefaultParser = DefaultParser()
private var cli: CommandLine

init {
    setupOptions()
    cli = parser.parse(flags, args)
}

/** Determine the flags allowed */
private fun setupOptions() {
    flags.addOption("e", "encode", false, "Encode message")
    flags.addOption("d", "decode", false, "Decode message")
}
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido! Si pones el código morse entre dobles comillas te lo toma como argumento?

Comment: Hola @JoseHermosillaRodrigo. Si lo pongo entre comillas me da exactamente el mismo error, en la mayoría de programas de terminal esto suele ser la solución, pero aquí no sirve. Parece que simplemente ignora las comillas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resuelto:
Al crear el objeto CommandLine añadimos el tercer argumento stopAtNonOption

```
cli = parser.parse(flags, args, true)
```